# Odd behaviour in android debugger

Tags: android, debugging

here is my simple code to determine if a field is empty or not.

```
private static boolean isPhoneNumberValid(){

    String phoneNo = "";

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNo))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{

        Toast.mekeText(this,"test",LENGTH.SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
```

it is obvious that the result of this code must be true and in fact, it is; but when I go step by step using android studio debugger, I see that after reaching return true; statement, the code goes right to return false; statement. but the overall result of this method is true.
any clue why this happens?

I already did a clean project and an invalid index.

Comment: Does it pass on the line "Toast.mekeText(this,"test",LENGTH.SHORT).show();" ??

Comment: @SinanNoureddine this line didn't run. as i said it goes to return false immediately. i guess its a debugger issue that i never had. I checked the code on another machine,debugger worked just fine and normal.